# Работа в Python одновременно на двух компьютерах

Tags: python

Я работаю над кодом в Python, который, грубо говоря, играет в онлайн игру, открытую в окне браузера.

Делаю скриншоты определенных участков экрана и совершаю движения мышки с помощью модуля autopy.

Я запускаю код в IDE Py Charm и открываю окно браузера на весь экран. Это не очень удобно, так как хочется наблюдать за данными, которые выводит программа.

В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Объединить дисплеи и запуская код на одном компьютере, загрузить в него координаты второго экрана для работы autopy. Насколько я знаю это достаточно сложно работать с координатами второго "виртуального" дисплея.
2. Возможно ли запуск кода одновременно на двух компьютерах? Или удаленное управление IDE со второго компа. Или хотя бы вывод данных с кода, запущенного на компьютере с браузером на другом компе?

Последний вариант более менее понятен, можно же сделать вывод данных, например, сообщений в телеграмм, но я хотел бы иметь возможность редактировать код, при его одновременной работе в окне браузера.

3. МОжет быть реально делать это все на одном компе, но окно браузера сделать прозрачным, чтоли, видимым для программы, но не видимым мне?

Comment: Если правильно понял, нужен удаленный интрепретатор. Например так — [Удаленный запуск в PyCharm Community Edition / Хабр](https://habr.com/post/256433/). Питон и браузер на удаленной машине, IDE на локальной.

Comment: а вариант «подключить второй монитор» не рассматривается?

Comment: Со вторым монитором сложности при работе с его координатами в autopy. Изначально этот модуль не видит второй монитор.

Comment: Зачем вам запускать через IDE на втором компьютере?